gitlab dynamic child pipeline in downstream [file not found]
any solution?
variables:
  SETTING1: "setting1"
  SETTING2: "setting2"

stages:
  - entry
  - trigger_child

entry_job:
  tags:
    - stg
  stage: entry
  script:
    - mkdir -p artifact
    - touch artifact/child-pipeline.yml
    - chmod 777 artifact/child-pipeline.yml
    - echo "job1.py" > artifact/artifact.env
    - echo "job2.py" >> artifact/artifact.env
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - artifact/

trigger_child_pipeline:
  tags:
    - stg
  stage: trigger_child
  needs: [entry_job]
  script:
    - |
      declare -a jobs
      while IFS= read -r line; do
        jobs+=("$line")
      done < artifact/artifact.env
      for job in "${jobs[@]}"; do
        echo "${job}:" >> artifact/child-pipeline.yml
        echo "  tags:" >> artifact/child-pipeline.yml
        echo "    - stg" >> artifact/child-pipeline.yml
        echo "  script:" >> artifact/child-pipeline.yml
        echo "    - echo 'running ${job}' ${SETTING1} ${SETTING2}" >> artifact/child-pipeline.yml
        echo "" >> artifact/child-pipeline.yml
        echo "" >> artifact/child-pipeline.yml
      done
      echo "Generated child-pipeline.yml!!!"
      cat artifact/child-pipeline.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - artifact/

trigger_child:
  stage: trigger_child
  needs: [trigger_child_pipeline]
  trigger:
    include: artifact/child-pipeline.yml
    strategy: depend

